# Как подружить REST API и концепцию DDD?

Tags: rest, ddd

Недавно я начал знакомиться с концепцией DDD, и возник вопрос - как правильно действовать при операциях CREATE и UPDATE, когда данные приходят через Web-API. Например, на некой форме на веб-странице мы заполняем поля, нажимаем "Сохранить". На адрес /api/customers летит POST-запрос с данными формы:

```
{
  "Id": "93967a3e-384f-459a-8b50-0a0f4cc66d66",
  "firstName": "Иван",
  "lastName": "Череззаборногузадерищенко",
  "zipCode": 245876,
  "city": "Самара",
  "street": "Николая Панова",
  "houseNumber": 64,
  "appartmentsNumber": 62,
}
```

На стороне Web-API он десериализуется в DTO-класс:

```
public class CustomerDTO
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public int ZipCode { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
  public string Street { get; set; }
  public int HouseNumber { get; set; }
  public int AppartmentsNumber { get; set; }
  public Guid CustomerStateId { get; set; }
}
```

Мы имеем следующую доменную модель (сделано очень грубо для демонстрации примера):

```
public class Customer: Entity, IAggreagtionRoot
{
        public Customer(Name name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
  public Name Name { get; private set; }
  public Address Address { get; private set; }
  public CustomerState State { get; private set; }

  public void ChangeState(CustomerState newState)
  {
    //some logic...
  }

  public void ChangeAddress(Address newAddress)
  {
    //some logic...
    Address = newAddress;
  }

  public void ChangeName(Name newName)
  {
    //some logic...
    Name = newName;
  }
}

public class CustomerState: Entity
{
  public static readonly CustomerState Regular = new CustomerState(new Guid("7beb8006-1b70-4d47-bb95-1976a2c18e9a"), "Regular");
  public static readonly CustomerState VIP = new CustomerState(new Guid("c27e9e0c-a2dc-4093-80f5-e75b66997746"), "VIP");

  public CustomerState(Guid id, string name)
  {
    Id = id;
    Name = name;
  }
  public string Name { get; private set; }
}
public class Address: ValueType
{
  public Address(int zipCode, string city, string street, int houseNumber, int appartmentsNumber)
  {
    ZipCode = zipCode;
    City = city;
    Street = street;
    HouseNumber = houseNumber;
    AppartmentsNumber = appartmentsNumber;
  }

  public int ZipCode { get; private set; }  
  public string City { get; private set; }
  public string Street { get; private set; }
  public int HouseNumber { get; private set; }
  public int AppartmentsNumber { get; private set; }
}

public class Name: ValueType
{
  public Name(string firstName, string lastName)
  {
    FirstName = firstName;
    LastName = lastName;
  }

  public string FirstName { get; private set; }
  public string LastName { get; private set; }
}
```

Вопрос 1. Как правильно из DTO-объекта изменить объект Customer? На ум приходит следующее:

```
public class CustomerService
{
  private CustomerRepository _customerRepository;
  public CustomerService(CustomerRepository customerRepository)
  {
    _customerRepository = customerRepository;
  }

  public void UpdateCustomer(CustomerDTO customerDto)
  {
    Guid customerId = customerDto.Id;
    Customer customer = _customerRepository.GetById(customerId);

    //Как мне дейстовать здесь?
    customer.ChangeName(new Name(customerDto.FirstName, customerDto.LastName));
    customer.ChangeAddress(new Address(customerDto.ZipCode, customerDto.City, customerDto.Street, customerDto.HouseNumber, customerDto.AppartmentsNumber));

    if(customerDto.CustomerStateId == CustomerState.VIP.Id)
      customer.ChangeState(CustomerState.VIP);
    if (customerDto.CustomerStateId == CustomerState.Regular.Id)
      customer.ChangeState(CustomerState.Regular);
    //Что-то вроде этого?

    //Может быть согласовать дизайн UI с дизайном доменной модели, и не позволять 
    //изменять статус с помощью полей формы, и изменять его отдельными действиями (например, специальными кнопками, 
    //которые инициируют POST-запрос www.site.ru/api/customers/2432352/PromoteToVip ?

    _customerRepository.Update(customer);
  }
}
```

Вопрос 2. Как быть, если я хочу присылать только изменения, а не весь объект целиком? Например, изменился только номер дома, и в целях минимизации пересылаемых данных, я хочу слать такой запрос:

```
{
  "houseNumber": 164
}
```

Как в этом случае мне изменить Value-type Address, если его конструктор требует всех параметров? 
Может быть как то вот так?:

```
Customer customer = _customerRepository.GetById(customerId);

var zipCode = customerDto.ZipCode == 0 ? customer.Address.ZipCode : customerDto.ZipCode;
var street = string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerDto.Street) ? customer.Address.Street : customerDto.Street;
var city = string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerDto.City) ? customer.Address.City : customerDto.City;
var appartmentsNumber = customerDto.AppartmentsNumber == 0 ? customer.Address.AppartmentsNumber : customerDto.AppartmentsNumber;
var houseNumber = customerDto.HouseNumber == 0 ? customer.Address.HouseNumber : customerDto.HouseNumber;

customer.ChangeAddress(new Address(zipCode, city, street, houseNumber, appartmentsNumber));
```

Вопрос 3. Что, если у объекта много свойств, скажем, 40. Скажем, 20 из них не влияют на согласованность модели (т.е. чисто информационные, и не требуется следить за их изменением). Делать для каждого методы установки значений (что ощущается мне грустным), или просто открыть их для редактирования (сделать сеттер публичным) внешнему коду?

P.S. Я думаю, что метод public void ChangeState(CustomerState newState) по канонам DDD следует убрать, и вместо него ввести методы что-то вроде PromoteToVip() и DowngradeToRegular(), но пусть в этом примере все будет как есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечу в порядке от простого к сложному.

**Вопрос №2**: как организовать присылку только изменений, а не всего объекта целиком. В REST по этому поводу есть устоявшаяся практика. Операцию *update* [детализируют](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) до *replace* и *modify*.

Первая, *replace* позволяет изменить объект целиком. Ей соответствует HTTP-метод `PUT`. Вторая, *modify*, позволяет изменить отдельные свойства. Ей соответствует HTTP-метод `PATCH`.

На вопрос, как изменить тип `Address`, чей конструктор требует всех параметров, отвечу: следуйте за предметной областью. Спросите *экспертов*, что для них адрес и можно ли менять его компоненты независимо друг от друга.

Может оказаться, что адрес разбивают на компоненты только для удобства ввода, а в действительности внутри домена адрес всегда нужен целиком. Тогда вы можете в явном виде указать эту особенность клиентам REST, вынеся адрес в отдельную структуру:

`{
  "Id": "93967a3e-384f-459a-8b50-0a0f4cc66d66",
  "firstName": "Иван",
  "lastName": "Череззаборногузадерищенко",
  "address": {
    "zipCode": 245876,
    "city": "Самара",
    "street": "Николая Панова",
    "houseNumber": 64,
    "appartmentsNumber": 62,
  },
}`

Пометив поля объекта `Address` обязательными, вы, фактически, подскажете клиенту следующее: адрес можно либо передать целиком, либо не передавать совсем (если речь идёт об операции *modify*).

> Небольшой комментарий по реализации. Насколько я вижу, у вас C#, а, значит, с высокой степенью вероятности и библиотека NewtonJson. Вы можете не заводить отдельные DTO-классы для объектов-значений, просто пометьте конструктор `Address(string zip, string city, string house, string apartment)` атрибутом `JsonConstructor`. NewtownJson сумеет собрать объект из JSON с помощью такого конструктора.

**Вопрос №3**: метод установки значения или сеттер? Противопоставление здесь надуманное: сеттер это синтаксический сахар для метода установки, который позволяет сделать код чище.

Если есть свойства, которые нужно устанавливать вместе, возможно, это объекты-значения?

```
customer.Name = new Name(customerDto.FirstName, customerDto.LastName);
customer.Address = new Address(customerDto.ZipCode, customerDto.City, customerDto.Street, customerDto.HouseNumber, customerDto.AppartmentsNumber);
```

Задействовать методы можно в сценарии, когда клиент вынужден постоянно менять несколько свойств, и всё время разные. Например, если бы у вас был объект *заказ*, у которого было бы несколько *статусов*, по которым объект мог бы переходить:

```
order.State = OrderState.Applied;
order.LastModified = timeProvider.Now;
order.Applier = httpContext.CurrentUser;
```

Вот такие бы конструкции следовало заменить на один метод:

```
order.Apply(httpContext.CurrentUser);
```

Именно это и есть сущность *инкапсуляции*: клиент не может разрушить состояние объекта извне, изменив только часть требуемых свойств. Сравните с именем и адресом выше.

**Вопрос №1**: изменение сущности по DTO-модели. В вашем коде всё вполне корректно. Дизайн UI конечно надо согласовать с моделью предметной области, потому что и то и другое, должно соответствовать представлениям пользователя. Наоборот, если вам приходится слишком трудно переводить объекты UI в сущности, это звоночек, что где-то вы отошли от DDD.

Используйте средства языка для выражения своих мыслей. В частности, такой сложный код:

```
if(customerDto.CustomerStateId == CustomerState.VIP.Id)
  customer.ChangeState(CustomerState.VIP);
if (customerDto.CustomerStateId == CustomerState.Regular.Id)
  customer.ChangeState(CustomerState.Regular);
```

Можно заменить на простой:

```
customer.State = (CustomerState)customerDto.CustomerStateId;
```

C# прекрасно понимает, что каждым enum-значением лежит целое число.

Comment: CustomerState же не enum, а `: Entity` и привести к нему `int` может быть не тривиально

Comment: @Grundy, да, увидел, спасибо. Пока оставлю ответ таким же, потому что на мой взгляд, `CustomState` не должен быть сущностью. Похоже, на уровень предметной области с уровня презентации просочились данные о том, что там `Id` и `Name`, но на уровне предметной области их нет.